# C# reflection - can't check nested base type

Tags: c#, reflection

I have a problem with checking if in the inheritance of my class, the inherited class implements some interface

```
public interface IUserClass : IBaseInterface<T, K> { }
public class UserClass : BaseClass<A, B>, IUserClass { }
```

and I check

```
typeof(UserClass).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IBaseInterface <,>))
```

and I get `false`. Even if I do

```
typeof(UserClass).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass<,>))
```

i get the same result
Why ?

Comment: `IBaseInterface <,>` is an open generic type, which can't exist.  You need to make it a closed generic in order for your code to ever return true.

Comment: I think, typeof(UserClass).BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(BaseClass<,>); is what your looking for